# org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json

I have created a login and register project in android using volley. The problem is that when I try to register that not show alert box with server response but on database it save new data. That's the error showing on android studio logcat and code

Error and Code Pic:

[image]

PHP Code:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried debugging or printing the response string? It's likely that you are not parsing according to the structure.

Comment: Please edit the code into your question

Comment: @hami perhaps this would be a good idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert a `String` to `JSONObject`, you should call `new JSONObject(myString)`. Casting will not work.

EDIT:
Looking at your code, why not just call `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);`.

Comment: still same problem